# matlab print: 'Cannot create output file '.\test.tif''

Tags: matlab

I am trying use the print command in MATLAB to save a scatter plot as a TIFF in the current folder.  However, I get the following error message: `Cannot create output file '.\test.tif'`

My code looks like the following:

```
hold on
plot(x,y,'-r','LineWidth',4)
plot(x2,y2,'--xk','LineWidth',4,'MarkerSize',10);
hold off
print -dtiff -r300 test.tif
```

Does anyone know how I can successfully save my file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You most probably don't have write permissions to create file in current directory. If you are working under Windows 7, it is possible that your working directory is somewhere under `Program Files` or at a drive root. Check it with `pwd` command.

Check also if you can save and other file, like MATLAB  m-file. You should have the same problem if it's a permission issue.

Another possible cause is that you already created a file under the same name and have it opened by another program.

Answer (score 3):

You'll also get a 'Cannot create output file' error if you have a malformed file name. For example:

```
figHandle = figure;
AnInt = 12;
print(figHandle,'-dpng', [AnInt .png])
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I have long title for the figure. This is not in your case. 
However, if you get a similar error due to that, use the following code to divide the title into two lines

title({'Performance comparison ';' between X and Y.'},...
    'interpreter','latex',...
'FontUnits','points',...
'FontWeight','normal',...
'FontSize',15,...
'FontName','Times');

Answer (score 0):

No doubt that permission to write files in the directory is the key. Matlab tries to save output file into the 'current folder' (mentioned in leftside window above workspace). Perhaps, the wrong folder is selected.

Comment: Are you convincet that this is an answer and not only a comment?

Comment: Why not? Unfortunately had the same problem today!